# Toolbar widget , NavHostFragment and bottomNavigationView - Android

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar

I have implemented jetpacks navigation ui in my android project by adding a NAVHostFragment in my project. I also have a "bottomnavigationview" widget for the bottom menu bar. I had a custom header toolbar in all my fragments but, I decided to go with the android "toolbar" widget. So I added the toolbar widget to my main_activity.xml. Now, the problem is after adding the toolbar widget, I don't see my home fragment, the page appears to be blank. If I remove the toolbar widget then its fine and i can see the home fragment(which is the first fragment mentioned in my navigation.xml). Any idea why this is happening and how I can get 
the navigation ui working like before and still be able to use the toolbar widget?

This is my main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Some Title"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_activity_navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how i implemented my navigation ui

```
private NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
@BindView(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainFrame);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController((BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view), navHostFragment.getNavController());
    }
```

This is my menu_bottom_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/departmentsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_black_18"
    android:title="Home" />
    <item android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_star_border_black_18"
    android:title="Favorite" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with my fragment layout and that is the reason it was blank. I fixed that and also, I added the following in my MainActivity.java and it worked !

```
private NavHostFragment navHostFragment;

    @BindView(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @BindView(R.id.appBar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        auth = new AuthenticationWrapper(this, new SimpleIdentityParser());
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainFrame);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navHostFragment.getNavController());
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController());
    }
```